# TermDocumentMatrix Error after Cleaning Corpus

Tags: r, tm, corpus, term-document-matrix

My problem is that I want to pass my corpus to the tm function termdocumentmatrix() and it fails with the error: `Error in UseMethod("meta", x): no applicable method for meta' applied to an object of class "character"`.

To begin with, I have a Dataframe named "auth" that looks like this:

| Author | Messages |
| --- | --- |
| 014588 | Hi; How are you |
| 123341 | Hello; Fine u? |
| 857635 | The weather is fine; It looks Sunny; There are some clouds |

The Author is self-explaining and the messages are all written by the specific author. The different Messages are separated by a semicolon.
The Code which transforms the dataframe to a corpus and cleans it looks like this:

```
auth_text <- auth$messages
auth_text2 <- replace_abbreviation(auth_text)
auth_source <- VectorSource(auth_text2)
auth_corp <- VCorpus(auth_source)

clean_corpus <- function(corpus) {
  corpus <- tm_map(corpus, removePunctuation)
  corpus <- tm_map(corpus, content_transformer(tolower))
  corpus <- tm_map(corpus, PlainTextDocument)
  corpus <- tm_map(corpus, removeWords, new_stop)
  corpus <- tm_map(corpus, stripWhitespace)
  corpus <- tm_map(corpus, bracketX)
  
  return(corpus)
}

clean_corp <- clean_corpus(auth_corp)
```

After cleaning the corpus it should be processed by:

```
corp_tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(clean_corp)
```

After starting the command the error message pops up as above described. I can't even view the corpus anymore. Could anyone help me out with this?

Comment: try running the cleaning functions seperately and see where the corpus dissappears. My guess at this line: `tm_map(corpus, bracketX)`. Since we don't know what `bracketX` does, it is difficult to tell. Also try using the dataset `crude` as this comes with tm. We don't have access to your data. Read the info of the [R tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info) and how to make a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing
`corpus <- tm_map(corpus, bracketX)`
did the job and the code is now functioning correctly